# facebook like button larger size

Tags: facebook

is there anyway to increase the size of the fb like plugin?

thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Yeah, target the iframe with CSS and scale it using CSS3. Something like this:

```
#fbiframe
{
transform: scale(2.5);
-ms-transform: scale(2.5); 
-webkit-transform: scale(2.5); 
-o-transform: scale(2.5); 
-moz-transform: scale(2.5); 
transform-origin: bottom left;
-ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
-moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else, my iframe didn't have an ID. So I targeted it with `.fb_iframe_widget iframe`.

Comment: Just a word of wrarning that this will break on mobile browsers (tested Chrome, Firefox)

Comment: Appears to be "not respected" on mobile but works on desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, it comes as is.  What's strange is that Google+ and Twitter allow you have have various sizes for their buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround, but it goes against [FB's policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies) of changing how their button looks. I imagine that you could probably create a bigger size FB like button and just use that...

[http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330183302/http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/)

Comment: "Somebody somewhere" said it might not be against policy to scale it...

Answer (score 1):

I using bootstrap and add property btn and btn-large css

```
<div class="fb-like btn btn-large btn-primary" data-href="#"
data-width="550" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="false"></div>
```

it can make the button become larger.

Answer (score 0):

These days the like plugin offers a "small" or "large" variant, viz data-size:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>`

You might be able to draw attention to it in other ways, also, like centering it, etc. see https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-increase-the-size-of-Facebook-like-button

Also try this:

```
.fb-like {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

(from https://www.babelscribe.co.nz/notes/resizing-facebook-like-buttons/) though it might mess up the positioning a bit.

And of course I suppose if you're truly desperate you could do the old trick of "your own custom like button" that just redirects them to a page with only the "real" like button or that pops up a modal with "just the like button" that they have to reclick again :|