# How can I change the size of the Facebook share button icon

Tags: javascript, facebook

The size of the share icon by default is very small. I want to replace the icon with a bigger one.

I am using the [Share Button API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) with the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

... and I placed this the code for my plugin wherever I want the share button to appear on my page:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="icon"></div>
```

I would like the icon used for such buttons to be larger, but cannot figure out how to do so.

fyi:  The share dialog should open on the same page, It shouldn't take the user to another page when someone click on the icon.

The facebook icon on this page is a great example,  :  http://plnkr.co/

Here's the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KjuhzK?s=s21QHFCrP9T66qsm&p=preview) for current code.

Comment: If you want a bigger button its better to use a custom one not the one from Facebook itself. As you can't change the size or design of that one

Comment: @RohitBatra Please share the link for the custom one.

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6138879/1741052

Comment: See also this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301189/how-to-make-a-very-large-facebook-share-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301189/how-to-make-a-very-large-facebook-share-button) - for using css to simply expand the display of the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [facebook like button larger size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938201/facebook-like-button-larger-size)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
.fb-share-button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(4.5);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your facebook share button(by adding it yourself) and resize it by adding the following code in your CSS file

```
.FBConnectButton {
  height: 15px;
  float: left;
  background-position-y: -251px;
  background-position-x: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a356e;
   }
 .FBConnectButton_Text {
  font-size: 8px ;
  height: 9px;
    }
 .fb_share_count_inner {
 height: 9px;
 position: relative;
  }
.fb_share_count .fb_share_count_right {
float: left;
 }
```

this will solve your problem just enter the height/font size and position of your button in the above code.
There are few answers already present on this forum they may be helpful

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676972/resize-scale-facebook-like-button-height-and-width)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820585/change-the-size-of-facebook-like-button)

Comment: This is not what we need, please take a look at the share icons at  http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Doesn't this not work because it's within an iframe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/583767/32453